# How to display uploaded csv file into tablular format in drupal 7

Tags: forms, drupal

I have created a form in drupal 7 and it has a field to upload file (csv file only ) now how to display uploaded csv file into table on form submit ?

[image]

Comment: What table? You have to explain this much better.

Comment: i just want to use following drupal inbuilt function and assign to some variable for further use:  

$res = theme('table', array( 'header' => $header, 'rows' =>$rows ));

How to get this done. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After go through various code exercises i have come up with solution which is as follows :

```
`function display_table($filename, $head=false) {
  $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
  $all_rows = array();
  $header = null;
  while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
    if ($header === null) {
      $header = $row;
      continue;
    }
    $all_rows[] = array_combine($header, $row);
  }
  $table = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $all_rows));
  return $table;
}`
```

Hope it would be helpful to others as well !

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about theme function, but you can do it on your own.

I.e. use:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

To read the file and then:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

to parse CSV.

Or, maybe:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

to read row by row. Anyway, you'll end up with looping trough rows so just print values the way you want, add markup around the values...

Comment: I have created following function for creating table but i want just header and row in seprate variables. 
function test($file_path, $header=false) {$handle = fopen($filename, "r"); echo '<table>';if ($header) {$csvcontents = fgetcsv($handle);echo '<tr>'; foreach ($csvcontents as $headercolumn){echo"<th>$headercolumn</th>";}echo '</tr>';}while ($csvcontents = fgetcsv($handle)){echo '<tr>';foreach ($csvcontents as $column) {echo "<td>$column</td>";}echo '</tr>';}echo '</table>';fclose($handle);}
Is it possible to have header and row seprate so that i can use theme() ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion and guidelines @MilanG .